Not able to create multiple long running session for a single excel file using Microsoft graph workbook api
We can create multiple long-running sessions for a single file using the Microsoft Workbook Create Session API, and the older sessions remain active for a short time. However, sometimes we receive an accepted (202) response when creating a new session, which prevents us from pushing new records into it.
We have a few questions about workbook sessions:

Can we create multiple sessions for a single Excel file?
If not, is the long-running session shared across all client applications?
Can multiple client apps each create their own session for the same Excel file?

alternative suggestions
